# Spark 3.1 String Array to Date Array Coversion Error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find out Whether this array contains this date or not. if yes i need to put yes in one column.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = dataset.withColumn("incoming_timestamp", col("incoming_timestamp").cast("timestamp"))
                .withColumn("incoming_date", to_date(col("incoming_timestamp")));
```

my incoming_timestamp is  `2021-03-30 00:00:00 after converting to date it is 2021-03-30`

output dataset is like this

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
|col 1                 |incoming_timestamp | incoming_date                          |
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------
|val1                  |2021-03-30 00:00:00| 2021-07-06                             |
|val2                  |2020-03-30 00:00:00| 2020-03-30                             |
|val3                  |1889-03-30 00:00:00| 1889-03-30                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have a String declared like this,

`String Dates = "2021-07-06,1889-03-30";`

i want to add one more col in the result dataset is the incoming date is present in Dates String.

Like this,

```
+----------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+
|col 1                 |incoming_timestamp | incoming_date                          |      result  |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
|val1                  |2021-03-30 00:00:00| 2021-07-06                             |  true        |
|val2                  |2020-03-30 00:00:00| 2020-03-30                             |  false       |
|val3                  |1889-03-30 00:00:00| 1889-03-30                             |  true        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for that first i need to convert this String into Array, then array_contains(value,array) Returns true if the array contains the value.

i tried the following,

METHOD 1

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date[] dateArr = Arrays.stream((dates.split(","))).map(d->(LocalDate.parse(d,
            formatter))).toArray(Date[]::new);
        
            it throws error, java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.time.LocalDate
```

METHOD 2

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

        Date[]  dateArr = Arrays.stream((Dates.split(","))).map(d-> {
                try {
                    return (formatter.parse(d));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }).toArray(Date[]::new);
            
    dataset = dataset.withColumn("result",array_contains(col("incoming_date"),dates));
```

it throws error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unsupported component type class java.util.Date in arrays
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by typecasting `String` to `java.sql.Date`.

```scala
import java.sql.Date


    val data: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(
      ("val1", "2020-07-31 00:00:00"),
      ("val2", "2021-02-28 00:00:00"),
      ("val3", "2019-12-31 00:00:00"))

    val compareDate = "2020-07-31, 2019-12-31"
    val compareDateArray = compareDate.split(",").map(x => Date.valueOf(x.trim))

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = data.toDF("variable", "date")
      .withColumn("date_casted", to_date(col("date"), "y-M-d H:m:s"))
    df.show()

    val outputDf = df.withColumn("result", col("date_casted").isin(compareDateArray: _*))
    outputDf.show()
```

Input:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
|variable|               date|date_casted|
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
|    val1|2020-07-31 00:00:00| 2020-07-31|
|    val2|2021-02-28 00:00:00| 2021-02-28|
|    val3|2019-12-31 00:00:00| 2019-12-31|
+--------+-------------------+-----------+

root
 |-- variable: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_casted: date (nullable = true)
```

output:

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+------+
|variable|               date|date_casted|result|
+--------+-------------------+-----------+------+
|    val1|2020-07-31 00:00:00| 2020-07-31|  true|
|    val2|2021-02-28 00:00:00| 2021-02-28| false|
|    val3|2019-12-31 00:00:00| 2019-12-31|  true|
+--------+-------------------+-----------+------+
```